# Is the phrase "in common" a noun?

Tags: nouns

Is "in common" a noun? Some dictionaries say adjective, but some (Longman) have a 2nd definition for "in common" as a noun.

Comment: Could you provide that relevant excerpt, where "Longman" gives that definition, so we all can see what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's a phrase, so it can't be a single part of speech. I think what you mean to ask is "is it a noun phrase," meaning a phrase that functions as a noun. For example "The bewildered dog" is a noun phrase.

"In common" is a participle phrase, which essentially function as adjectives. A good test is to take a sentence with a proper noun or a pronoun and try to replace the noun with your phrase. If you can think of sentence that works, then you probably have a Noun Phrase. (You can do the same for other types of phrases).

Comment: *"In common" is a participle phrase*: Er, could you explain that a bit more?

Comment: *"We have **friends in common**"* matches pretty closely to *"We have **shared friends**"*. Since the latter is clearly an *adjectival* usage, I think this is enough to show that the former must be so too. OP has simply misunderstood the implications of the fact that in this context, the *single word* "common" is essentially a *noun*. That doesn't mean the two-word *phrase* is also a noun.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Could you help us understand how *"We have* ***shared friends***" is *adjectival* usage?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ah, I think I might now understand. Perhaps you're saying that "shared" is a modifier in NP structure headed by "friends"?

Comment: _Our friends are shared (in common)_ = _Our friends are shared (among us)_ = _We have friends shared (among us/in common)_ = _We have friends that are shared (among us/in common)_ = _We have shared friends_ = _We have friends in common._

Comment: There's "We have shared friends" which could be seen as similar to "We shared [friends]", and it could also be seen as similar to "We have [common friends]".

Comment: @F.E. A participle phrase is a phrase that begins with a participle e.g. "in the house." They can be used adjectivally (I kissed the **girl** _in the red dress_) or adverbially (I **hit** the clown _with a bat_).

Comment: @JohnLawler So this is an adverbial phrase attaching to the verb not an adjectival one attaching to the noun? The OED has “to have in common” falling under **sense 2b for *have*** “with complement or adverbial extension, particularizing the relation of the object or expressing some qualification, condition or limitation thereof.” It gives as a citation: **“1634 Sir T. Herbert** *Trav.* 3  — They used to have their Wives in common.” I’m sure more modern examples could be found in Utah. :)

Comment: 'A participle phrase is a phrase that begins with a participle e.g. "in the house." ' 'In' is a preposition, not a participle.

Comment: There are entirely too many grammatical terms that begin with P. It's easy to confuse polysyllabic terms.

Comment: @tchrist: The particular sense of "in common" is decided in context, as you point out. _They have their brown eyes in common_ doesn't mean that they share the same eyes.

Comment: They have many differences in common?

Comment: @Edwin: And well they might! [*Whether one calls it "genetic variability" or "the infinite wisdom of nature," the meaning is the same: Each of us is different. In the fantastic variability of nature man finds that certain organisms **have differences in common.***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22organisms+have+differences+in+common%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)